# Should a Bluetooth-communicating NSStream require a separate thread?

Tags: ios, nsthread, nsstream, nsrunloop, external-accessory

Using ExternalAccessory to talk to a Bluetooth device, I'm using the input and output `NSStreams` supplied by `EASession` to send messages to it.

In Apple's `EADemo` example, it schedules both streams to the main thread's run loop. However, I have noticed that in many networking-related applications that use `NSStream`s developers prefer to create a separate thread to perform read/write operations and schedule the streams to the new thread's run loop.

For a Bluetooth device, should such behavior (creating a separate thread) be implemented or scheduling it to the main thread's run loop won't cause major blocking issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in general preferred to do as less as possible on main thread. I think EADemo does this on main thread as in context of small example it is applicable, but in context of big production application it is not.